# Как не повторить один и тот тоже запрос SELECT * FROM?

Tags: php, sql

В коде один и тот же запрос sql, повторяется несколько раз в коде, как можно сократить код что бы не каждый раз его заново написать, в функции можно его поставить или каким образом это делается?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM client_name WHERE cl_name = '$client'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $family = $row['family '];
  $work = $row['work'];
}
```

Comment: Да.
Вы правильно сказали. Создаете файлик, в котором храните функции/классы, отвечающие за запросы к бд, подключаете его после коннекта к бд например, и уже эту фию/класс вызываете одной строчкой

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну да правельно думаешь - процедурный стиль;

```
function DB($client){
$query = "SELECT * FROM client_name WHERE cl_name = '$client'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $value['id'] = $row['id'];
  $value['name'] = $row['name'];
  $value['family'] = $row['family'];
  $value['work'] = $row['work'];
}
return $value;
}
```

через классы почти так же

```
class db{   
public function DB($client){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM client_name WHERE cl_name = '$client'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $value['id'] = $row['id'];
      $value['name'] = $row['name'];
      $value['family'] = $row['family'];
      $value['work'] = $row['work'];
    }
    return $value;
    }
}
```

Если у тебя часто идут по каким то причинам повторяющиеся запросы 
можно так же посмотреть в сторону микрокэширования функций... 
[MikroCachePHP](https://github.com/StasToken/MikroCachePHP)

Comment: Попробовал в функции сохранить, но когда вызываю ее дает ошибку: Notice: Undefined variable: id in ...

Comment: Так ну давай разбираться с простого, он тебе говорит что у тебя переменная не определена, сдеай в цикле var_dump($row); die(); давай посмотрим что у тебя возвращается, результат дампа в студию. у тебя в таблице кстати точно есть поле с id ?

Comment: А погоди я кажется осознал: ты когда вызываешь функцию поди забываешь обработать возвращаемый результат... ( мне что подсказывает что это так) `$res = DB($client); у тебя в $res будет лежать массив с данными далее надо поместить его в каждую свою переменную, например так  $id = $res['id'];
  $name = $res['name'];
  $family = $res['family '];
  $work = $res['work'];`

Comment: Вот так теперь получилось, спасибо)